# Classloader loading a class for None when foreach is used on it

Tags: scala, jvm, classloader

I define custom JFR events like this:

```
  @Name("xxxx.jfr.PerfScope")
  @Label("PerfScope scope")
  @Category(Array("Java Application"))
  @Description("Scope with a tracked performance")
  @StackTrace(false)
  class PerfScopeEvent(
    name: String
  ) extends jdk.jfr.Event

  val hasJFR = try {
    FlightRecorder.register(classOf[PerfScopeEvent])
    true
  } catch {
    case _: NoClassDefFoundError =>
      // this is expected when running on JDK 8
      false
  }
```

When using the event the code does this:

```
    val event = if (hasJFR) {
      Some(new PerfScopeEvent(scopeName))
    } else {
      None
    }

    event.foreach(_.begin())

    // ....

    event.foreach { e =>
      e.end()
      e.commit()
    }
```

The purpose of the code is to skip the `PerfScopeEvent` class functionality when running on Java 8, where class `jdk.jfr.Event` is not available.

I have verified in the debugger the `hasJFR` is constructed fine, when running on Java 8 it is false because an exception `NoClassDefFoundError` is thrown while calling `FlightRecorder.register(classOf[PerfScopeEvent])`.

The trouble is that in the "using the event part" I get an exception as well. The exception is thrown when `event.foreach(_.begin())` is executed. This is confusing me.

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/jfr/Event
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jdk/jfr/Event
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jdk.jfr.Event
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 22 more
```

I can prevent the exception by using `if (event.isDefined) event.foreach(_.begin())` instead (and the same for the second use).

What difference does wrapping in the `if (event.isDefined)` have? Why does classloader load the class `jdk/jfr/Event` when using `foreach` directly?

I was able to create a minimal code which still shows the same issue:

```
import jdk.jfr._

object OptionalJFR  {

  @Name("com.github.ondrejspanel.jfr.PerfScope")
  @Label("PerfScope scope")
  @Category(Array("Java Application"))
  @Description("Scope with a tracked performance")
  @StackTrace(false)
  class PerfScopeEvent(@Label("name") val name: String) extends Event

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val s = (s: PerfScopeEvent) => ()
  }
}
```

The bytecode generated from this is:

```
public final class OptionalJFR$ {
  public static final OptionalJFR$ MODULE$;

  public static {};
    Code:
       0: new           #2                  // class OptionalJFR$
       3: dup
       4: invokespecial #22                 // Method "<init>":()V
       7: putstatic     #24                 // Field MODULE$:LOptionalJFR$;
      10: return

  public void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: invokedynamic #48,  0             // InvokeDynamic #0:apply:()Lscala/Function1;
       5: astore_2
       6: return

  public static final void $anonfun$main$1(OptionalJFR$PerfScopeEvent);
    Code:
       0: return

  private OptionalJFR$();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #56                 // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static final java.lang.Object $anonfun$main$1$adapted(OptionalJFR$PerfScopeEvent);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokestatic  #58                 // Method $anonfun$main$1:(LOptionalJFR$PerfScopeEvent;)V
       4: getstatic     #64                 // Field scala/runtime/BoxedUnit.UNIT:Lscala/runtime/BoxedUnit;
       7: areturn

  private static java.lang.Object $deserializeLambda$(java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokedynamic #76,  0             // InvokeDynamic #1:lambdaDeserialize:(Ljava/lang/invoke/SerializedLambda;)Ljava/lang/Object;
       6: areturn
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `foreach`, the lambda (an instance of `Function[PerfScopeEvent, Unit]` in this case) is constructed, and then `foreach` is called.  In the case of `None`, `foreach` doesn't execute the lambda.

This means that side effects of constructing the lambda will happen, even if the lambda is never executed.  Classloading is such a side effect.

By wrapping the call to `foreach` in an `if`, the lambda is not created until after the condition check.

That said, once you're doing an `isDefined` check, it's probably worth considering unwrapping the `Some` and not using `map`/`flatMap`/`foreach` and friends (it will be more performant by not constructing lambdas, though there are valid reasons to maintain an absolute style).  Also note that `eq None` is almost certainly faster than `isDefined`.

Comment: Exactly, once I discovered I need to use `isDefined`, I switched to `null` instead of `None` - the code is quite low-level anyway, I only wanted to use `Option` because it is more idiomatic Scala.

Comment: The only thing (this is more for anyone reading this later) to beware of when taking the `null` course, is to be very careful about encapsulating the possibly-`null`-ness.